# Are normal subgroups of a profinite group with finite index closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a profinite group and $H \subseteq G$ be a normal subgroup with $[G:H] < \infty$, i.e. $H$ has finite index.

**Question**: Is $H$ closed?

**Problems**:

I have a lot of trouble to understand these profinite groups in general. I know that they are inverse limits where every finite group is endowed with the discrete topology. Then we say that this inverse limit is endowed with the product topology of these discrete groups which I find hard already since I only worked with finite products before. I really have no clue how open/closed sets look like.

The only proof I understood is that in a compact topological space, every open subgroup is exactly the closed subgroups of finite index. I heard that there is some relation to the normal subgroups, but I did not really understand it. [I need something to understand the proof in this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061439/characterization-for-the-continuity-of-weil-representations)

Could you please explain this concept to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Half an answer: If you assume that $G$ is finitely generated then every subgroup of finite index is open. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/FLTJensen.pdf Theorem 1.1. I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this paper page 4

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6837.pdf

It says that the group $A_5^\mathbb{N}$ is in "class 2", and they define class 2 to be compact groups having nonclosed subgroups of finite index.

I can't find a concrete subgroup of $A_5^\mathbb{N}$ which satisfies this but at least you know it's false.

Comment: You won't find a concrete such subgroup: their existence highly relies on the choice axiom. Such subgroups (of $S^{\mathbf{N}}$ with $S$ an arbitrary nontrivial finite group) can be found by picking a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\omega$ on $\mathbf{N}$, namely the normal subgroup $\{(g_n)\in S^{\mathbf{N}}:\lim_\omega g_n=1\}$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks. Thinking about that it really makes sense now as measurable subgroups of compact groups of finite index are necessarily open (hence closed). So there could only be non-measurable counter-examples and usually the axiom of choice is the only way to construct non-measurable things.

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer to your question based on my limited knowledge on this subject. According to the [definition](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Profinite_topology#:%7E:text=Definition,of%20subgroups%20of%20finite%20index.), any normal subgroup of finite index is open. Also, as multiplication is continuous, all its left cosets are open. Now the union of all left cosets of $H$ other than  itself must be open, and hence $H$ must be closed.

Comment: If you take a non-congruence subgroup of finite index in $SL_2(\widehat Z)$, intersect it with its conjugates, you get a finite-index normal subgroup which is not open.

Comment: @Echo: Thank you for the enlightening comment. It helps me to clarify my misunderstanding on this subject. So. how should this be corrected?